# New to Python - need help opening window

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am working on my first code.

The ONLY code i have typed out is below. I understand it is supposed to open a blank window, but when i try to run the code, a window does not open and the terminal just reads:

```
C:\Users\dliot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:/Users/dliot/Desktop/DsCode/Game'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am i doing wrong?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,200))

while True:

    pass
```

Comment: How do you run your program? Are you using the command line or some editor?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running some variant of `python3 -m Game`, when you should either be doing

```sh
$ python3 game.py  # or whatever the name of your file is
```

Or, to make the call with `-m` work as intended, rename your file to `__main__.py`

Comment: I don't understand what "-m" means, but I changed the name to what you said and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: `-m` is Python-speak for "module", it basically means you want to run a whole directory instead of a single file. As your code grows, you will naturally find yourself learning about this.